# DotnetLibary with Gremlin query

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, gremlin

Is there any Dotnet library to connect to Neo4J Database using "Gremlin Queries". I could see Dotnet library "Neo4K.Driver.dll". 
I guess this DLL supports only Cypher queries? Is there anyway I can use "Gremlin Query" using Dotnet library for Neo4J database?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j.Driver.dll supports connections to the database. It may run Gremlin queries. Also, Neo4j just released a GraphQL plug in, which provides API functionality and may be useful for your project? https://neo4j.com/blog/graphql-neo4j-graph-database-integration/

Comment: Thank you  so much for the help!!